# Getting Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\quotes\paginator.php on line 32

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I am trying to do pagination but i am get the

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\quotes\paginator.php on line 32

What should I do to get rid of this error? I have to pages as below.
I read the reference given to me and took help from the code but i am getting fatal error. as above .please take look in my code and tell where i am lagging.
I have two pages. index.php and paginator.php
why i am getting fatal error I cant understand.

index.php

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>

    <?php
    require_once 'Paginator.php';

    $con       = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'root', 'pixster', 'quotes' );
    $limit      = ( isset( $_GET['limit'] ) ) ? $_GET['limit'] : 25;
    $page       = ( isset( $_GET['page'] ) ) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
    $links      = ( isset( $_GET['links'] ) ) ? $_GET['links'] : 7;
    $query      = "SELECT table2.col2 AS a,table1.col2 AS b, table1.col1 AS  c, table1.q_url AS d FROM table2, table1 WHERE table2.col1 = table1.col4 ";//  AND table2.friendly_url= '".$authorname."'";

   $Paginator  = new Paginator( $con, $query );

   $results    = $Paginator->getData( $page, $limit );
   ?>
   <?php for( $i = 0; $i < count( $results->data ); $i++ ) : ?>
   <tr>
   <td><?php echo $results->data[$i]['$i']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $results->data[$i]['$row['b']']; ?></td>

    </tr>
    <?php endfor; ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>quotes Pagination</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <h1>PHP Pagination</h1>
    <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered table- rounded">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th width="20%">Sr. No</th>
    <th width="20%">Quotes</th>

      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <?php for( $i = 0; $i < count( $results->data ); $i++ ) : ?>
      <tr>
      <td><?php echo $results->data[$i]['$i']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $results->data[$i]['$row['b']']; ?></td>

      </tr>
      <?php endfor; ?></tbody>
      </table>
      <?php echo $Paginator->createLinks( $links, 'pagination pagination-sm' ); ?> 
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

paginator.php

```
      <?php

     class Paginator {

    private $_con;
    private $_limit;
    private $_page;
    private $_query;
    private $_total;


  public function _construct( $con, $query ) 
 {

 $this->_con = $con;
 $this->_query = $query;

 $rs= $this->_con->query( $this->_query );
 $this->_total = $rs->num_rows;

 }

 public function getData( $limit = 10, $page = 1 ) {

$this->_limit   = $limit;
$this->_page    = $page;

 if ( $this->_limit == 'all' ) {
    $query      = $this->_query;
 } else {
    $query      = $this->_query . " LIMIT " . ( ( $this->_page - 1 ) *     $this->_limit ) . ", $this->_limit";
  }
  $rs             = $this->_conn->query( $query );

    while ( $row = $rs->fetch_assoc() ) {
    $results[]  = $row;
    }

    $result         = new stdClass();
    $result->page   = $this->_page;
    $result->limit  = $this->_limit;
    $result->total  = $this->_total;
    $result->data   = $results;

    return $result;
    }  

  public function createLinks( $links, $list_class ) {
   if ( $this->_limit == 'all' ) {
    return '';
    }

   $last       = ceil( $this->_total / $this->_limit );

   $start      = ( ( $this->_page - $links ) > 0 ) ? $this->_page - $links :   1;
  $end        = ( ( $this->_page + $links ) < $last ) ? $this->_page +   $links : $last;

  $html       = '<ul class="' . $list_class . '">';

    $class      = ( $this->_page == 1 ) ? "disabled" : "";
    $html       .= '<li class="' . $class . '"><a href="?limit=' . $this->_limit . '&page=' . ( $this->_page - 1 ) . '">&laquo;</a></li>';

    if ( $start > 1 ) {
    $html   .= '<li><a href="?limit=' . $this->_limit . '&page=1">1</a>  </li>';
     $html   .= '<li class="disabled"><span>...</span></li>';
     }

    for ( $i = $start ; $i <= $end; $i++ ) {
    $class  = ( $this->_page == $i ) ? "active" : "";
    $html   .= '<li class="' . $class . '"><a href="?limit=' . $this->_limit  .     '&page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a></li>';
  }

    if ( $end < $last ) {
    $html   .= '<li class="disabled"><span>...</span></li>';
    $html   .= '<li><a href="?limit=' . $this->_limit . '&page=' . $last .  '">' . $last . '</a></li>';
   }

 $class      = ( $this->_page == $last ) ? "disabled" : "";
 $html       .= '<li class="' . $class . '"><a href="?limit=' . $this- >_limit . '&page=' . ( $this->_page + 1 ) . '">&raquo;</a></li>';

  $html       .= '</ul>';

  return $html;
  }
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: ahem `$this->_conn->`

Comment: where should i make change bro??

Comment: you've declared it as `$this->_con = $con;`

Comment: You never seem to check for connection problems or errors while query execution.

Comment: take it up with the answers now. I've said what I had to say to start you out.

Comment: btw, there's another syntax error. Let's see if answers pick up on it.

Comment: i made this mistake here buddy not i my code please find the answer other than this

Comment: @AlpeshPanchal buddy, then please fix it here as well, coz it will be first thing thing everyone will look at. and how about http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php ? any error while connecting ?

Comment: @Sirko my query and db connection are right. i have checked them.

Comment: now you went and fixed the typo for `$this->_conn->` without marking it as an edit. that's not how things are done here. and I stand at getting downvoted for it and others also. I performed a rollback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you're declaring your connection as

```
$this->_con = $con;
```

but calling it as `$this->_conn->`

then you're constructor's incorrect

```
public function _construct( $con, $query )
               ^ missing one here
```

*edit:* and should be: (I think it's obvious that it should be added)

```
public function __construct( $con, $query )
                ^^ there are 2 now
```

you've a missing underscore for the construct

Always check for errors when you're in the development stage.

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: where am i missing underscore borther?? i cant see it is there in above code.

Comment: @AlpeshPanchal two `__`

Comment: @AlpeshPanchal here `_construct` in `public function _construct( $con, $query )`

Answer (score 0):

The problem seem to be with the line:

`$rs             = $this->_conn->query( $query );`

Your class `Paginator` has variable named `_con` not `_conn` a classic copy-paste error.

**Edit:**

After the OP mentioned that the code he pasted here was incorrect, it seems like the `_con` object is null, but it was set to on the constructor. However, on a closure look, there is no constructor function at all.

The syntax for the constructor magic method is defined [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php#object.construct)

Comment: i made this mistake here buddy not i my code please find the answer other than this

Answer (score 0):

`$this->_conn` to `$this->_con` in Paginator.php

i.e

```
$rs = $this->_con->query( $query );
```

Comment: i made this mistake here buddy not i my code please find the answer other than this

Comment: @AlpeshPanchal check Fred's answer. I think he found the problem `__contruct`.